# Emails response sent from client save to my database in php

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

We have a ticketing support system on our own webapp.
The user logs in to their own dashboard, goes to the ticket section, inserts a new ticket with a subject and a message.
When they click on SUBMIT REQUEST, the system:

1. saves user reference, subject and message to MySQL database
2. sends an email to all our technical people using phpmailer

When a technician completes the request or needs more info from the user:

1. write the response to ticket section
2. an email is sent automatically with response to end user.

Email sent by our PhpMailer script inserts custom header to email like a ticket reference that is unique.

At this point the final user receives the email with response and a button link with: "CLICK HERE TO LOGIN TO YOUR DASHBOARD AND ANSWER TO THIS TICKET"

So the final user need to login again to answer this ticket.

## My question is....

Is it possible to build a system where the user can reply directly to the email using our preferred client (Outlook, Thunderbird, etc...) and my webapp "intercept/recognize" that email and save the body response to our database directly based on a contained ticket reference?

I don't understand where start from? Any example on the web?

Comment: What do you mean by intercept the email? in that context you are "outside of your site" so to reply you have to add a link to your site like as you done.

Comment: @Sfili_81 I need to "check email received" using PHP and, extract info by email received to ticket@demoexample.com (by custom header I think) and save the body to my sql db.

Comment: send email and save in database ?

Comment: @Dlk yes, like github...if you answer ti a ticket from your email client, then you see the response also in webpage of github project, ticket section

Comment: You have to integrate your app with your email server (or ESP) somehow. The how is far too broad a question for SO. Start by looking through the documentation for your email server (or ESP) to see which kind of notifications (if any) it supports.

Answer (score 3):

As @Peter said, this is really too broad for SO, however, a simple example to point you in the right direction will probably help.

Most mail servers allow you to map inbound email addresses to scripts, and this is what you need to provide an email access point into your app. Taking postfix as an example, the simplest way is to use a pipe alias. Postfix has an aliases file in `/etc/aliases`, and you need to add an entry that maps an inbound address to a script:

```
support: "|/path/to/your/script.php"
```

then run `newaliases` to make postfix pick that up. Note that this assumes that this postfix server is already handling your domain, and the actual address is `support@yourdomain.com`.

You need to ensure that your script starts with a "shebang" (to tell it how to run the script), and mark it as executable:

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
$outfile = fopen('emaillog.txt', 'a');
while (!feof(STDIN)) {
    fwrite($outfile, fread(STDIN, 1024));
}
fwrite($outfile, "\n\n");
fclose($outfile);
exit(0);
```

This example script (untested!) simply reads the message (which is presented on standard input) and appends it to a log file, but of course you can do anything else you like here – connect to a database, talk to APIs, etc.

then mark the script as executable so that postfix can run it:

```
chmod +x /path/to/your/script.php
```

Be aware of the user that this script is run as – the script is run by postfix, so the postfix user will need appropriate permissions if it needs to write files.

There's a more comprehensive article [here](https://thecodingmachine.io/triggering-a-php-script-when-your-postfix-server-receives-a-mail).